# Notification content: sizes, colors, margins, paddings

Tags: android

I created a custom notification (I'll add more content into it later) and I want that its icon and text would be the same as for default notifications, how I can do it?

[image]

Now I just set some constants in my xml (which isn't good):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/notifiation_image"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/texts"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notifiation_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textContentTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Content title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textSubText"
                android:layout_below="@id/textContentTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subtext" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

service:

```
RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification);

mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
        ...
        .setCustomContentView(notificationView)
        ...
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set icon and text would be the same as for default notifications, then Don't Use Custom Layout.

You can use Default Notification Builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)  
                    .setContentTitle("Title")      
                    .setContentText("SubText")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Then, if you are setting custom layout,Then Notification will follow custom xml design rules, that you have created. So If you change xml (by adding textsize,padding and margin,textstyle etc..),So that look like default notification.

Answer (score 1):

```
Follow this code:    


RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.notification);

            Intent .....
            .....


            PendingIntent .......
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic...)
                    .setTicker(getString(R.string......))
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(Intent)
                    .setContent(remoteViews).setOngoing(true);
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageleft,
                    R.drawable.icon_notification);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,
                    getString(R.string.....));
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, getString(R.string......));
            NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: what it changes?

Answer (score 0):

To make your notification's icon and content look similar to other system notifications, apply NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle to your notification with setStyle method of Notification.Builder as below. This API allows you to provide a custom layout for the content area normally occupied by the title and text content, while still using system decorations for the notification icon, timestamp, sub-text, and action buttons. There is no need to apply any padding, margin or textsize. NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle API takes care.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)  
                .setContentTitle("Title")      
                .setContentText("SubText")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                // at last add this method
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()); // this makes your notification's style similar to system notification's style
```

Further, optionally, you may apply support library styles such as TextAppearance_Compat_Notification for the text and TextAppearance_Compat_Notification_Title for the title in your custom layout as in the example below. This would prevent varying of background color for the notification across different devices and versions.

```
 <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="@string/notification_title"
android:id="@+id/notification_title"
style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try To Put Text Size

```
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textContentTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Content title" />

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSubText"
            android:layout_below="@id/textContentTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Subtext" />
```